# Opencv. cv2.drawMatches() not drawing matches. Opencv 3.0

Tags: opencv, orb

Not drawing matches. Opencv 3.0, fully updated Ubuntu. The code runs but it doesn't show any matches. The test region is directly cut and copied from the image to match.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)


img1 = cv2.imread('images/ingrassroi.png',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('images/ingrass.png',0)

img3 = img1.copy()

# Initiate ORB detector
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

# compute the descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)

# Sort them in the order of their distance.
matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

# Draw first 10 matches.
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:10],None, flags=2)

cv2.imshow("Matches",img3)
cv2.waitKey(-1)
```

[image: Picture to match]

[image: Test image]

[image: Matches]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the image to match with was too small. It was not finding any key points in the train image. I enlarged the area that I cropped from the test image and it found matches and correctly identified the cigarette butt in the image. Just an FYI if you decide to try the FLANN based matcher on the same page in the OpenCV Python tutorials, be sure to define FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6.